# slideToggle function working separately

Tags: jquery, html

My issue is about jQuery and its slideToogle() function. I am trying to use this function more than  times on 1 page and I am asking if its possible to have one div ID or Class that will be in this function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          $("class or div").click(function(){
            $("class or div").slideToggle("fast");
          });
});
```

My goal is to have several divs and when I click on them they will expand/close SEPARETLY. It works great while I only have one div. When I set all of my divs to class (lets say class of the first div is `class="class"` and class of the div that is supposed to move is `class="div"` ) when I click on my `<div class="class">` every single `<div class="div">` expands.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          $(".class").click(function(){
            $(".div").slideToggle("fast");
          });
});
```

I have tried to go around this problem but my (so far) only working code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#class1").click(function(){
        $("#div1").slideToggle("fast");
      });
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#class2").click(function(){
        $("#div2").slideToggle("fast");
      });
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#class3").click(function(){
        $("#div3").slideToggle("fast");
      });
    });
```

Is it really necessary to use that many lines of code (especially when Iam planning to have more than 15 of these kind of divs) ?

Thanks for your help.

My HTML:

```
<img class="prace" src="images/kresby/lambo.jpg">
<div id="flip1"> 1. Lamborghini Gallardo Superleggera</div>
<div id="panel1">Lamborghini Gallardo Superleggera</div>

<img class="prace" src="images/kresby/corvette.jpg">
<div id="flip2">TOGGLE</div>
<div id="panel2">TEXT</div>

<img class="prace" src="images/kresby/bumblebee.jpg">
<div id="flip3">TOGGLE</div>
<div id="panel3">TEXT</div>
.
.
.
```

My Script:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#flip1").click(function(){
        $("#panel1").slideToggle("fast");
      });
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#flip2").click(function(){
        $("#panel2").slideToggle("fast");
      });
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#flip3").click(function(){
        $("#panel3").slideToggle("fast");
      });
    });
```

My CSS:

```
#flip1,#flip2,...{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: #191919;
    border-radius:10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#panel1,#panel2...{
    text-align: center;
    background: url("images/b.PNG"); ;
    display:none;
    padding: 50px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px ridge #ffff66;
}
```

Comment: can you share the html sample so that we can see the relationship between the class and div element

Comment: is the `div` element a child of `class` element or sibling/next element etc

Comment: No need for `$(document).ready(function(){` every time, keep it just once and then you can have your code inside .

Answer (score 0):

If it’s possible, to move the second `<div>`s into the first ones, you could do it that way:

```
<div class="flip">Headline 1
  <div class="sub">Desciption</div>
</div>

<div class="flip">Headline 2
  <div class="sub">Desciption</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".flip").click(function(){
    $(this).children(".sub").slideToggle("fast");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use $(this) inside the events to slide only the particular element that trigerred the event and not all the elements with the same class.

According to your HTML structure, you could also use next().

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div[id*='flip']").click(function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
  });
});
```

It would be better if you use a common class for all the divs with id 'flip1', 'flip2', etc., maybe a class named 'flip'.

Then you could simply use the following :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".flip").click(function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add classes `flip` and `panel` to the elements

```
<img class="prace" src="images/kresby/bumblebee.jpg">
<div id="flip3" class="flip">TOGGLE</div>
<div id="panel3" class="panel">TEXT</div>
```

then

```
$('.flip').click(function(){
    $(this).next('.panel').toggle()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally will go for the hover effect . The actual part of the code, which toggles stuff, i will keep them inside a function and then use hover to pass the ID s.

**JS :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function makeThemToggle(toggleID, nextDivID){
        $("#"+toggleID).click(function(){
            $("#"+nextDivID).slideToggle("fast");
        });
    }

    var nextDiv = '';

    $("#flip1").hover(function(){
        nextDiv = ($("#flip1").next().attr('id'));
        makeThemToggle('flip1',nextDiv);
    });

    $("#flip2").hover(function(){
        nextDiv = ($("#flip2").next().attr('id'));
        makeThemToggle('flip2',nextDiv);
    });

    $("#flip3").hover(function(){
        nextDiv = ($("#flip3").next().attr('id'));
        makeThemToggle('flip3',nextDiv);
    });

});
```

Working JS fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/QXbAZ/2/

But  **beware** : This way, the toggling effect in conjunction with hover gets very pronounced and there may be 2 or 3 instances of element toggling involved .

Answer (score 0):

You also may use `each()` like this after adding a class to every flip :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".flip").each(function(){
      $(this).click(function(){
        $(this).next().slideToggle("fast");
      });
    });
 });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CjZVm/1/)